# Pass asp control as parameter to javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to have this function:

```
function count(inputObj, ouputObj)
{
   outputObj.value = inputObj.value.length;
}
```

And I would like to call it in this way:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUSERGUID" runat="server" onkeyup="count(this, document.getElementById('<%=txtUSERGUIDLength.ClientID%>'));" onkeydown="count(this, document.getElementById('<%=txtUSERGUIDLength.ClientID%>'));" />

<asp:TextBox ID="txtUSERGUIDLength" runat="server" />

<asp:Label ID="lblUSERGUIDLength" runat="server" Text="chars" />
```

But I keep getting a javascript error that says: 'outputObj' is undefined.  Can I call this function like this or am I going the completely wrong direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have this inside of a server tag it won't execute the server side code:

```
<%=txtUSERGUIDLength.ClientID%>
```

If you are going to do it do something like

```
<script language='javascript'>

var g_clientID = '<%=txtUSERGUIDLength.ClientID%>'

<script/>
```

then do:

```
onclick(this, document.getElementById(g_clientID))
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your page source, I think you'll find that the "onkeyup" event handler still has the server side code in it.  Since you are setting a property on a server control, the "<%=  %>" code is not executed.  You'll have to move this to a separate javascript function if you want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can insert parameters in this manner for server side controls.

You can set these parameters in your server side code:

```
txtUSERGUID.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", yourEventHandlerScript);
```